# Take values directly from CSV file and pass as inputs

Tags: input, import, output

How to take multiple values from csv use it as input in function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going one step to far when attempting to convert the `dataList` vector.

Iterate over the `dataList` vector like you do now, but then instead of an inner loop you simply get `vec[0]` and `vec[1]` and [convert the strings to `double`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof), that you [*emplace*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) into the `test_values` vector.

Perhaps something like

```
for (auto const& vec : dataList)
{
    test_values.emplace_back(std::stod(vec[0]), std::stod(vec[1]));
}
```

Comment: hi i have been trying it , still no luck , just to make sure iterate it in the main or in the class?

Comment: @zack The loop shown in my answer is a replacement for after "Get the data from CSV File".